# Problem with SVG Filters to make a specific color transparent in an image

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters, css-filters

I found a svg filter with multiple filter-effects to make a specific color in an image transparent.
I created an image with two colors Red and Black and I am making the black
color transparent.

The filters are working correctly except that instead of
making all the black pixels transparent, there is still a thin black line where 
the black and red colors meet.

I am not able to find out what is going wrong.

```html
<svg>
  <image id="ID_GraphicOff" display="inline" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="188" height="148" x="0" y="0" opacity="1" filter="url(#filter_CTT_00)" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6v30l0g1oqsuk6s/Red.png?raw=1"></image>

 <filter id="filter_CTT_00" RefCount="1">
    
   <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="100.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 100.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 100.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0" result="stage1Addition"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="stage1Addition" type="matrix" values="-1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0  0.0 -1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0  0.0 0.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0" result="stage1Inversion"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="100.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -0.0 0.0 100.0 0.0 0.0 -0.0 0.0 0.0 100.0 0.0 -0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5" result="stage1Subtraction"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feBlend in="stage1Inversion" in2="stage1Subtraction" mode="screen" result="stage1ColorZero"></feBlend>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="stage1ColorZero" type="matrix" values="2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 -1.0" result="stage1AlphaCorrection"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="stage1AlphaCorrection" type="matrix" values="1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0  1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0  1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0" result="stage2RGBAddition"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="stage2RGBAddition" type="matrix" values="1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.499999  0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.499999  0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.499999  0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0" result="stage2RGBThresholdRaise"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feComponentTransfer result="stage2Discretization">
      <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="1.0 0.0"></feFuncR>
      <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="1.0 0.0"></feFuncG>
      <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="1.0 0.0"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="stage2Discretization" type="matrix" values="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -1.0 1.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0" result="stage2ColorAlphaZero"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5" result="stage3AlphaZeroPointFive"></feColorMatrix>
   
    <feBlend in="stage2ColorAlphaZero" in2="stage3AlphaZeroPointFive" mode="screen" result="stage3ColorAlphaZero"></feBlend>
   
    <feColorMatrix in="stage3ColorAlphaZero" type="matrix" values="2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 -1.0" result="stage3Correction"></feColorMatrix>
   
  </filter>
  
</svg>
```

Codepen link for the HTML -
https://codepen.io/manjunath-vadigeri/pen/ZEbvozX

Please remove the `filter="url(#filter_CTT_00)"` attribute in the image tag to see the unfiltered 
image.

Comment: Probably antialiasing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That filter is way too complicated for what you're trying to do. This is a much easier version that avoids the artifacts (which are probably created by your feComponentTransfer)

```
 <filter id="filter_CTT_00" RefCount="1">
   <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0   0 1 0 0 0   0 0 1 0 0  3 -1 -1 0 0" result="stage1Addition"/>
  </filter>
```